# How to do sub menus in BlazorStrap?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am learning to create Blazor server side web app, using the BlazorStrap component. I have been researching on https://blazorstrap.io/navbars to figure out how to do 2 or 3 level sub menus without any success. Can one use BlazorStrap to create multi-level navbar? If Yes,how? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is what I have for TopMenu.razor:

```
<BSNavbar IsExpand="true" IsDark="false" Color="Color.Light">
<BSNavbarToggler @onclick="onclick" />
<BSCollapse isOpen="@IsOpen" IsNavbar="true" IsOpenChanged="OpenChanged">
    <BSNav IsList="true" Class="mr-auto" IsNavbar="true" Alignment="Alignment.Left">
        <BSNavItem>
            <BSNavLink IsActive="true" Href="javascript:void(0);">Home</BSNavLink>
        </BSNavItem>
        <BSNavItem IsDropdown="true">
            <BSDropdownToggle Color="Color.Light">Transactions</BSDropdownToggle>
            <BSDropdownMenu>
                <BSDropdownItem Href="javascript:void(0);">Direct Transfer</BSDropdownItem>
                <BSNavItem IsDropdown="true">
                    <BSDropdownToggle Color="Color.Light">FIFO / LIFO</BSDropdownToggle>
                    <BSDropdownMenu>
                        <BSDropdownItem Href="javascript:void(0);">FIFO / LIFO (One to Many)</BSDropdownItem>
                        <BSDropdownItem Href="javascript:void(0);">FIFO / LIFO (Many to One)</BSDropdownItem>
                    </BSDropdownMenu>
                </BSNavItem>
            </BSDropdownMenu>
        </BSNavItem>
    </BSNav>
</BSCollapse>
```

```
    @code
{
    bool IsOpen { get; set; } = true;
    void onclick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        IsOpen = !IsOpen;
        StateHasChanged();
        Console.WriteLine("Navbar Class->" + IsOpen.ToString());
    }
    void OpenChanged(bool e)
    {
        IsOpen = e;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        Console.WriteLine("OpenChanged->" + IsOpen.ToString());
    }

    bool IsOpen2 { get; set; } = true;
    void onclick2(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        IsOpen2 = !IsOpen2;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the bindings on your nested drop down that toggle the state of the drop down. This is the mark up for your nav bar with the correct bindings.

```
<BSNavbar IsExpand="true" IsDark="false" Color="Color.Light">
    <BSNavbarToggler @onclick="onclick" />
    <BSCollapse isOpen="@IsOpen" IsNavbar="true" IsOpenChanged="OpenChanged">
        <BSNav IsList="true" Class="mr-auto" IsNavbar="true" Alignment="Alignment.Left">
            <BSNavItem>
                <BSNavLink IsActive="true" Href="javascript:void(0);">Home</BSNavLink>
            </BSNavItem>
            <BSNavItem IsDropdown="true">
                <BSDropdownToggle Color="Color.Light">Transactions</BSDropdownToggle>
                <BSDropdownMenu>
                    <BSDropdownItem Href="javascript:void(0);">Direct Transfer</BSDropdownItem>
                    <BSNavItem IsDropdown="true">
                        <BSDropdownToggle Color="Color.Light" @onclick="onclick2">FIFO / LIFO</BSDropdownToggle>
                        <BSDropdownMenu @bind-IsOpen="@IsOpen2">
                            <BSDropdownItem Href="javascript:void(0);">FIFO / LIFO (One to Many)</BSDropdownItem>
                            <BSDropdownItem Href="javascript:void(0);">FIFO / LIFO (Many to One)</BSDropdownItem>
                        </BSDropdownMenu>
                    </BSNavItem>
                </BSDropdownMenu>
            </BSNavItem>
        </BSNav>
    </BSCollapse>
</BSNavbar>
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks. But my followup question will be - if I have 20 second level submenus then I need to create IsOpen3, IsOpen4, IsOpen5, ... etc?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, but I wouldn't recommend having a drop down list with twenty levels and would look in to refactoring your navigation as clicking through twenty drop downs just to get to a link would be a frustrating experience for the end user.